# Error Installing ICE on Python

Tags: python, ice

I have python 3.5 and 2.7 installed (I don't know if this might be the problem) and I need to use ZeroC Ice and when I do:

```
sudo pip install ice
```

I get the following error in the terminal:

```
Collecting ice
  Using cached ice-0.0.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-MoRI5C/ice/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
        import ice
      File "ice.py", line 46, in <module>
        import urllib.parse
    ImportError: No module named parse

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-MoRI5C/ice/
```

But parse is already installed (I guess):

```
sudo -H pip install parse
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): parse in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

How can I solve this please?

THanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple mistake, try this instead.

```
pip install zeroc-ice
```

This should do the correct job.

Comment: install with pip3. It should work. parse is another submodule under urllib. No need to install parse as a module itself.